# BuddyBuild tests fail, but on local works fine

Tags: android, unit-testing, build

Hi I have problem with tests build on [BuddyBuild](http://buddybuild.com).

Method what i want to test:

```
    public static String convertTimeToDepartureDate(long timeInMillis) {
       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
       SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
       return format.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
```

and this is my test:

```
    @Test
public void timeToDepartureTest() throws Exception {
        String dateDeparture = TimeUtils.convertTimeToDepartureDate(timeMillis);
        assertEquals("Date have wrong format or numbers!", "7 Oct 16:45", dateDeparture);
}
```

And this is one solution what i found on the internet but doesn't work:

```
    @Test
public void timeToDepartureTest() throws Exception {
    synchronized (Calendar.getInstance()) {
        String dateDeparture = TimeUtils.convertTimeToDepartureDate(timeMillis);
        assertEquals("Date have wrong format or numbers!", "7 Oct 16:45", dateDeparture);
    }
}
```

On our machines works fine. All tests passed. But on BB doesn't work.
This is log from BB console:

```
...
   :app:testDebugUnitTest
    com.package.dao.TimeUtilsTest > timeToDepartureTest FAILED
    junit.framework.ComparisonFailure at TimeUtilsTest.java:46
    com.package.dao.TimeUtilsTest > timeToMinutesAndHoursTest FAILED
    junit.framework.ComparisonFailure at TimeUtilsTest.java:52
    com.package.dao.TimeUtilsTest > timeToSpecificFormatTest FAILED
    junit.framework.ComparisonFailure at TimeUtilsTest.java:70
    com.package.dao.TimeUtilsTest > timeToOpeningHoursTest FAILED
    junit.framework.ComparisonFailure at TimeUtilsTest.java:64
12 tests completed, 4 failed
...
```

I think BB works fine. We have a problem in our test. Can you some idea how to solve it? 
Thanks you.

Comment: Same thing here. We already asked to Buddybuild support team, let's see if we can find a proper solution for this soon.

Comment: Seeing the same thing on iOS and BB too. Have also asked them for help.

Comment: Let me know how they answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in timezone. BuddyBuild use PST and local machines / code use default EST or whatever. **Solution is defined timezone for every time value.**

for `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
 //...           
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
 //...
```

and for `Calendar`:

```
//...
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dateConverted);
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
//...
```

And now test will be passed.